# How to filter results based on year in date field in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

So I'm writing a program which, when given user input, (using JDBC), of a year will return all the orders of that given year. I'm storing the date as 'OrderPlaced' in my Orders table with format 'dd-MMM-YY'. However, I'm a bit stumped how to go about retrieving the information based solely on the year of entry. Would it be with the use of a LIKE statement? or is there an in-built way in which I could filter dates in oracle?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `LIKE` with dates.  Here are three alternatives:

```
where to_char(order_placed, 'YYYY') = :year

where extract(year from order_placed) = :year

where order_placed >= to_date(:year || '0101', 'YYYYMMDD') and
      order_placed < to_date(:year + 1 || '0101', 'YYYYMMDD')
```

The third has the advantage that it is most likely to use an available index on `year_of_entry`.

Comment: Thanks! Although I can't figure out how to use what you've given me. At the moment i'm trying SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE to_char(2017, 'YYYY') = :OrderPlaced; but it's telling me "bind variable OrderPlaced not declared" and the same when I replace OrderPlaced with year